# is_plugin_active() not defined on active plugin, in the thumbnails.php file

Tags: plugins, php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, fatal-error

When I try to access the details on a product using WooCommerce I get this error message.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_plugin_active() in
>   /home2/samiam/public_html/wp-content/plugins/featured-image-from-url/includes/thumbnail.php
>   on line 55

This is the code that is sitting right over this line.

```
function fifu_get_html($url, $alt) {
    if (is_plugin_active('sirv/sirv.php') && strpos($url, "sirv.com") !== false)
        return sprintf(' ', $url);
```

`return sprintf('<!-- Featured Image From URL plugin --> <img src="%s" alt="%s"></img>', $url, $alt);}<code>`

Any suggestions will help thanks!

The site is [fratzkeart.com](http://fratzkeart.com)

When you try to access one of the products it shows this error from the WooCommerce product page... this worked not to long ago I think an update broke it. Here is one of the products URLS >> [fratzkeart.com/index.php/product/solo-paper/](http://fratzkeart.com/index.php/product/solo-paper/)

Comment: Maybe you are calling this file directly instead through the WP API? In that case, none of the WP functions are available.

Comment: Also, `is_plugin_active()` is loaded only in WP admin area.returning. So, how and when do you execute that function?

Comment: In is_plugin_active is call from front-end you need to include plugin.php file as mention here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active

Comment: @toscho♦ How would I know that I was calling it directly the site is accessing this php. So I'm pretty sure I am calling it through a WP API as you can see through the site that I exampled.

Comment: @cybmeta it doesn't give me different results when I am logged in with an admin WP.

Comment: @Benoti I added the admin php code. I'm not exactly sure where I should add the theme code though. It seemed a little vague. Thank you, but I don't have much progress.

Comment: Did you add include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); at the top of the function ?

Comment: @Benoti I know, but we didn't know where the code in the question was executed, that is why I asked about that .... and we still don't know exactly. Anyway, as it is, it seems a support issue for a [third party plugin (Sirv CDN and Image Manager)](https://github.com/wp-plugins/sirv), you whould ask to the plugin developers, [third party plugins are off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @cybmeta, agree with you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is\_plugin\_active function doesn't exist](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9345/is-plugin-active-function-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it works for me :)

```
// We need plugin.php!
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

        $plugins = get_plugins();

        foreach ($plugins as $key => $value) {
            if ( $value['Name'] == 'Aest Plugins' ) { // <-- name plugin validate
                if( is_plugin_active( $key ) ){
                    echo "plugin {$value['Name']} is active";   
                }else{
                    echo "plugin {$value['Name']} is desactive";    
                }
            }
        }
```